# Connecting to a 169.254.x.x network

Tags: networking, dhcp

For some reason a network i need to connect my raspberry pi to uses the ip ranges 169.254.x.x and the pi won't connect. I understand that the range 169.254.x.x is supposed to be reserved for some special purpose, but pretty much any other device connected to this network works.

Is there any way to get the raspberry pi to work here as well?

Other details:
RPI 4
Latest raspbian

Comment: Whoever set-up that network doesn't understand the link local address block. Private networks should use 10.xxx.xxx.xxx/8 172.[16-31].xxx.xxx/16 or 192.168.xxx.xxx/24 networks.

Comment: That may be, but this is how they have set up their network and i have to adapt to it.

Comment: It's wrong, so go and ask the owner of the network how you're expected to connect to it and what routes need to be used.

Comment: Hah, i barely got access to the network in the first place. In certain sectors of industry people have a preferred way of doing things and are quite protective about it. I've gotten clear indications that if i make any kind of fuss for the operators, i'm out.

Answer (score 2):

The 169.254.x.x range (technically a /16 network) known as fe80::/10 for IPv6 is used when a DHCP server is not found on the local network or cannot issue a new IP address to the requesting device.  At this point the Automatic Private IP Addressing, or APIPA kicks in.

You can set the address up manually using dhcpcd.conf in Stretch / Buster along the lines of:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=169.254.0.115/16
static routers=169.254.0.1
static domain_name_servers=169.254.0.1
```

BUT there are a few things that you need to understand:

- Its bad practice.  Its *possible* that the next device will automatically assign itself a used address thought they **should** use ARP to stop this...
- Some switches and routers will not pass data out of this network e.g. to WiFi or other switches
- Some routers will not apply NAT for these addresses so Internet connection is not possible
- Some devices assign random addresses each time they boot.  Others use the MAC address of the card to calculate the address

Saying all of that - I use IPv6 link local as my router will not pass these and my ISP will not say when (or IF) they will provide IPv6 functionality :-)

Personally, I would set a DHCP server up (e.g. PI-HOLE or ISC-DHCP) and let it control the network.

Comment: Oh, so you can set up the static config and it will work? I have limited options when it comes to controlling the network (industrial with grumpy admins...), but i can ask for a reserved address. Why they have used this range i have no idea, but it is not the first time i have encountered it. Seems like a common thing in some circles i suppose. Last time i encountered it i had a raspberry pi 3 (couple of years ago) and that worked fine.

Comment: I would get them to issue you a static address from the DHCP server - they will need the MAC address of the Pi though.  One argument I have seen for this is if the network is hacked its 'harder' to find your way around (its not but what the heck).

Comment: @Andyroo You can, of course do this, **BUT** the Pi, in common with standard procedures already has a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)
I would guess the device is designed to connect to a DHCP server.

Comment: You are right with your warnings, so for my opinion it's not a good idea to show how to set a static link local ip address. B.t.w. these ip addresses are defined only for local use, so ALL routers will not route these ip addresses, otherwise they violate the specification.

Comment: ufortunately, the solution posted does not work. The Pi is assigned the address, but is unable to reach anyone on the network. Other machines on the network are however able to reach the pi. Seems like there is some setting that simply prevents the pi from even trying.

Comment: When you say other devices can reach the Pi what do you mean - is this via a PiNG or what?  How are you trying to reach the other computers? Have tech support confirmed you are on the same network segment or configured the switch port differently? (Forgive delay - not been a good time health wise - not COVID - other problems).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "169.254.x.x network"
This is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)

This indicates the Pi was unable to obtain an IP Address.

Comment: This network uses that range. Everything else gets addresses in those ranges and are able to reach other machines on that network.

Comment: What is this mysterious "network"? [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) are **NOT** routable - they work **ONLY** on the link level.

Comment: It is an industrial network at a wastewater treatment plant. I have pretty much zero say in the network topology. I do however have a router here and i set it up with the dhcp 169.254.1.x for testing. I connected two PCs to it and they got 1: 169.254.1.2 and 2: 169.254.1.3. They can communicate fine, but the pi, not so much.